# How to refresh JTABLE with fixed header column content

Tags: java, jtable, refresh, row

I have problem with how to refresh JTable with fixed header column, actually I can display table content, if I click menuitem then it will be refreshed based on which menuitem clicked . Here my source code :

```
public class PanelTableItem {
    Object rowData[][]=null;
    JTable mainTable ;
    JTable fixedTable;
    public JPanel getPanelDetailItem(String separate,String group) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String tseparate=null;
        String tgroup=null;
        if (separate!=null && !separate.isEmpty()) {tseparate=separate;}else {tseparate="COLLECTION 1";}
        if (group!=null && !group.isEmpty()) {tgroup=group;}else {tgroup="SOFA";}

        final Object rowData[][]=new OtherClass().getItem(tseparate, tgroup);
        final String columnNames[] = { "Item Code", "Name"};

        final TableModel fixedColumnModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
            public int getColumnCount() {return 1;}
            public String getColumnName(int column) {return columnNames[column];}
            public int getRowCount() {return rowData.length;}   
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {return rowData[column][row];}
        };
        final TableModel mainModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
            public int getColumnCount() {return columnNames.length - 1;}
            public String getColumnName(int column) {return columnNames[column + 1];}   
            public int getRowCount() {return rowData.length;}
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {return rowData[column + 1][row];}
        };

        fixedTable = new JTable(fixedColumnModel);
        fixedTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

        mainTable = new JTable(mainModel);
        mainTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

        ListSelectionModel model = fixedTable.getSelectionModel();
        mainTable.setSelectionModel(model);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainTable);
        Dimension fixedSize = fixedTable.getPreferredSize();
        JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
        viewport.setView(fixedTable);
        viewport.setPreferredSize(fixedSize);
        viewport.setMaximumSize(fixedSize);
        scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, fixedTable.getTableHeader());
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(viewport);

        JPanel panelTableItem=new JPanel();
        panelTableItem.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelTableItem.setVisible(true);
        return panelTableItem;
    }
}
```

Here my otherclass.getItem :

```
public Object[][] getItem(String separate,String group) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        setConnection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM mitem WHERE tampil=1 AND separate='"+separate+"' AND groups='"+group+"' ORDER BY name";
        System.out.println(SQL);
        Object[][] arritem= new Object[getCountRowSQL(SQL)][getCountRowSQL(SQL)];

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getURL());
        try{
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            try {
                stmt.setQueryTimeout(getTimeout());
                final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                try {
                    int ctr=0;                    
                    while (rs.next()) {                     
                        arritem[0][ctr]=rs.getString("item_code");
                        arritem[1][ctr]=rs.getString("name");
                        //arritem[2][ctr]=rs.getString("item_code");
                        ctr++;
                    }
                }finally {
                    try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
                }
            }finally {
                try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }
        }finally {
            try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }
        return arritem;
    }
```